# Is there a simple way to determine what font is being used in the user's title bar?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, titlebar

I'd like to find out what font the user has defined for a window. If they are using MS Sans Serif, then there are characters they cannot display. I'm assuming most people will be using Tahoma or Segoe UI but that's an assumption I'm not prepared to make within my program.

Can I easily and safely query the user's type of font for the title bar (non-client area)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Drawing.SystemFonts.CaptionFont
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Drawing.SystemFonts.CaptionFont should give you what you're looking for.